# (Stripe) CRM_Core_Payment_Manual::setAPIParams() Fatal Error

Tags: civicontribute, stripe

CiviCRM 5.24.4/Wordpress 5.4

Getting hourly alerts from Cron, pertaining to some kind of API failure with Stripe. I suspect it has to do with the version-setting, but I'm unclear on how to address this.

In fact, (as originally posted here), I'm getting really strange behavior from Stripe payment processing; in addition to returning an error 100% of the time ("This PaymentIntent's amount could not be updated because it has a status of requires_capture. You may only update the amount of a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses: requires_payment_method, requires_confirmation, requires_action." -- there's another thread here about that already), the Stripe dashboard shows a consistent $200 addition to all payments (these are in steps of $25, $50, $100, & $500 . . . and whatever I choose has exactly $200 extra tacked on).

Seems a little nuts. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Just restored a backup from a few days ago, pre-Stripe, and rebuilt everything, letting CiviCRM set the webhooks, etc. Same exact issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna mark this as answered, for now, as I've logged it as an extension issue.

The core of the problem, just FYI, seems to be that the auto-webhook process is failing (it appears to work, and a webhook does indeed appear on the Stripe dashboard, but the errors persist and I'm *hoping* that the real weirdness (the additional $200) is at least related to this.